# How do I start DB2 on an Amazon EC2 Volume?

Tags: amazon-ec2, db2

I've got an instance of DB2 installed as part of an IBM WebSphere Portal development AMI on the Amazon EC2 cloud. Its installed a separate, persistent file system from the rest of the AMI.

Yesterday, the AMI was terminated, and DB2 went down as part of that. It was not shut down cleanly, just terminated.

Today, I am trying to restart the WebSphere portal server, which needs to connect to the DB2 instance. But the DB2 instance is down.

So I need to restart my DB2 instance, but how to do that is not immediately obvious. Can someone tell me what I need to run to get it going again?

OS is SuSE Linux, DB2 version is 9.1

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got this to work. What I had to do was su to the owner of the db2 instance (in this case, the user name was db2inst1)

Under that users home directory, there is a directory called "sqllib/adm" and under that is an executable called "db2start" which must be run.

This script initially failed for me with an "SQL6048N" error. To fix this, I had to change the name of the host in the sqllib/db2nodes.cfg file - the host name on the current instance was different because the host name changes when you terminate and restart an AMI image. This host name also had to be changed in the file /opt/ibm/db2/V9.1/default.env

Comment: Make sure there is a DB2 service set up in your System Services under YaST; this will make sure that DB2 is started automatically when your instance boots up.